# Search for string in file and write to multiple files

Tags: java

If the String is found within the file in more than one place, I want to write it to file2. If that String is found in the original file OR file2, write to file3. If String was matched in any of the previous three files, write to file4.

I have used several BufferedWriters which does not work. Help here? What do I replace with "fileIAmSearching"?

```
import java.io.*;    
import java.util.*;    

public class SortGeneSym {  

   public static void main (String [] args) {


        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "FormattedHumanRNA" ));

            String line;
            String genesym;

            while ((line= br.readLine() ) != null)
            { String arr[] = line.split( "\t");
                genesym = arr[0];
                 //variable genesym is the first String in line

                if(fileIAmsearching.contains(genesym)) {
                    BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "1Occurance" ));
                    bw1.write (line);
                    // a match!
                    break;
                }
                else if (fileIAmSearching.contains(genesym)) {
                    BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "2Occurance"));
                    bw2.write (line);
                    break;
                }

                else if (fileIamSearching.contains(genesym)) {
                    BufferedWriter bw3 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "3Occurance"));
                    bw3.write (line);
                    break;
                }

                else (fileIamSearching.contains(genesym) = null ) {
                     BufferedWriter bw0 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( "0Occurance"));
                     bw0.writer (line);
                     break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println ("file probs dne");
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: What's the question? `br.contains(genesym)` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: It doesnt. How am I supposed to search a file for "genesym" within a file and write it to another file it is it found?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `line.contains`

Comment: I believe that just searches that single line, right?

Answer (score 0):

See the API for the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, it contains several methods that allow you to search the character values of the object. For instance, you can read each line from the file using a BufferedReader, and then search each line (String) using the contains method:

```
while ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ){
    if ( line.contains(whatImSearchingFor) ){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Some other comments:

1. If you wish to search in a case sensitive manner, you can convert both 'needle' and 'haystack' variables to upper or lower case and then search.
2. If you wish to search for phrases which may overlap line breaks, you can use a StringBuilder to append each line of the File (with or without the line breaks depending on the context), then search that StringBuilder (or convert to a String)
3. No reason to break out of the if/else conditionals
4. You should close the BufferedWriters (and BufferedReaders). This is often done using a try/catch/finally, where the finally will always be called to close the Writer - you might wish to create these outside the while loop, write to them as needed, then close after the loop is complete.

Comment: This does not work because it searches a single line for this String. I wish identify the first string of every line, and if they appear more than once, print that repeated string to another file. I have many "genesyms" as well as thousands of lines.

Comment: Your requirements make no sense: `identify the first string of every line`. The line is a String. Do you mean the first **word** of every line? Be explicit - we cannot read minds. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask